# Why is pdftk no longer available on Cygwin?

Tags: linux, pdf, cygwin, pdftk

`pdtfk` is often considered the go-to non-proprietary tool for serious transformations of PDF files, and as such it used to be available from the Cygwin package repository, but I can't find it anymore. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pdftk` relied on the `gcj` package, which is the [GCC compiler for Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java). GCJ was officially removed from GCC in September 2016, and therefore subsequently discontinued by the package repositories for the various distros. As a result of this, many repositories have also dropped the (no-longer-buildable) `pdftk` package itself from their repositories, including [Fedora](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2014-March/196367.html), [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pdftk/+bug/1757314) and [Cygwin](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/cygwin/2016-08/msg00656.html).

I gave up attempting to build `pdftk` for my own Cygwin system because of the `gcj` dependency, and because I couldn't trust a tool from developers who insist on using dependencies that have been deprecated for 4 years now. An [email exchange here](https://github.com/documentcloud/docsplit/issues/123#issue-52316206) from 2014 - two years before GCJ was finally dropped by GCC - cites the developer of `pdftk` as saying:

> Yes, I've heard that they're dropping support for libgcj. We have been
> working on a new pdftk that doesn't depend on libgcj, but it is
> currently pre-beta.

However, it seems nothing came from this "pre-beta", since the last time the official `pdftk` had any update at all [was in 2013](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-version-history/).

I personally had two options available to me: to install the Windows binary of the `pdftk`, which would result in an installation separate to the rest of my Cygwin environment, or to use a different but similar tool that is available from the Cygwin repository, such as `qpdf`. Given what I now knew of the last time that `pdftk` was  updated, I opted to use `qpdf` and so far haven't been disappointed. The one criticism I have of the tool is that its website and documentation looks a lot less prettier (and therefore, less approachable) compared to `pdftk`'s, but the tool itself appears to have all of the same functionality.

`qpdf` is also available and actively maintained on most other major Unix-like systems, including [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qpdf) and [Fedora](https://fedora.pkgs.org/30/fedora-updates-x86_64/qpdf-8.4.2-1.fc30.x86_64.rpm.html).

#### EDIT:

Thanks to *user1686* for pointing out `pdftk-java`. [`pdftk-java`](https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk/-/releases) is a community project that arose since the dropping of `pdftk` from the major repositories, with the goal of porting the original `pdftk` project entirely to Java, and thereby extricating it from any dependency on the `gcj` C compiler. The project is still fairly new, having had its first release in the middle of 2019, and it wasn't an option for me due to not being available in the Cygwin repository, but it is available on [Arch](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/pdftk/), [Debian](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/pdftk-java/pdftk.pdftk-java.1.en.html) and [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/pdftk-java).

Comment: Pre-beta or not, Arch seems to be [successful at building pdftk 3.x](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/pdftk/) without needing gcj. The latest update to the repository was 3 days ago.

Comment: @user1686 Thanks for reminding me about that project, I've integrated your comment into the answer.